# How to build Python 2.7 for Angstrom BeagleBoard XM

Tags: linux, opencv, python-2.7, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I would like to use OpenCV via the Python CV2 library on my BeagleBoardXM running Angstrom.  I have Python 2.6 installed, but CV2 requires Python 2.7.

When compiling from source on the BB-XM, the compiler core-dumps.  I think this is due to memory limitations.

OPKG does not seem to have a pre-built package for Python 2.7.  Is my only option to build on a PC and install manually?  If I mounted the BB-XM file system over the local network could I build/install in one step?

Installing software from source (that I personally haven't written) is my greatest weakness with Linux (I always seem to fall into dependency hell), especially when the target is different than the host OS.

Suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). This distro provides both Python 2.7.x and 3.x as also OpenCV 2.4.2. So you won't have to deal with dependency hell.